# OAuth 2.0 - When should an access token be renewed with refresh token?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm currently using OAuth 2.0 to access the Google API. From my understanding, I should use the returned refresh token to renew the access token. Should this be refreshed before it expires or should it be when the user requests data from the api using an access token that has expired?

If it should be done before it expires, should I just be running a cron job to update out of date tokens?

I'm using node.js and mongodb, if that has any bearing on the recommended solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: add some code/config examples if you want to see some suggestions how i would do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be seamless.

When the user requests data from the API using an access token that has expired, this should trigger your framework to fail, renew, then retry.

No need for any cron jobs or stuff like that in the apps i've created.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I guess my confusion came from why I need a refresh token, when (with google at least) reauthorising is seamless? Thanks for code offer too, should be ok from here on in!

Comment: Could you please elaborate with example? I've tried to build an application which authenticates any user with a valid google authentication and shows him his calendar events for each day. I am storing the access and refresh token in db and using the refresh token when I am making a google calendar api call, which is working if I log in immediately after I have agreed to give access in the consent page. But if I try after a day, I see 401 errors.