# How to get a new Google oauth access token from refresh token in passportjs

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, passport.js

there seems to be some conflicting advice on how to get an access token from a refresh token:

This SO answer says passportjs doesn't get involved with refreshing the access token and it should be done via cron job:

[Refresh token in Passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593446/refresh-token-in-passport-js)

This SO answer says "No need for any cron jobs...when the user requests data from the API using an access token that has expired, this should trigger your framework to fail, renew, then retry."

[OAuth 2.0 - When should an access token be renewed with refresh token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436351/oauth-2-0-when-should-an-access-token-be-renewed-with-refresh-token)

What's the simplest way to ensure we're always giving Google a valid access token? Right now, we're just storing the refresh token in the database and never using it, which forces users through the "allow / deny permissions" flow every time their access token expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches.  One is to just detect when the access token fails (with 401 I believe) and then refresh it and re-use it.  However, most of the APIs that yield access tokens also tell you their expiry time, so you can just remember that and, when you’re about to use, if it’s less than say 10 min before expiry time, refresh then.  If all else fails you could use the tokeninfo endpoint when you get a new access token, to find out its lifetime.

Comment: Great, that makes sense. I see in Google's Oauth documentation that a successful token response with include: "expires_in: the remaining lifetime on the access token". 

But passport-google-oauth's verify function only accepts:

function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done)

I'd like to save the expiry time and check against that as it seems most rigorous, but it seems passport-oauth-google hasn't implemented this.

So, switching to the strategy of detecting a 401 response - anyone know if it is possible to detect when an access token fails without modifying passport-google-oauth?

Comment: Posted the followup Q [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598720/get-an-oauth-access-token-from-refresh-token-in-passportjs) since it's a passportjs specific question.